# Coletar valor de um retorno

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
{"finalOFX":{"0":"276.67"},"0":null}
```

Assim está retornando do PHP, como no javascript dou alerta e exiba somente o `276.67`
Tentei assim `alert(dados.finalOFX)`, porém aparece `Object: Object`

Comment: Não percebi ainda o que esperas/queres que apareça?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve acessar ao propriedades do objeto, sendo, `dados` o objeto que contém: `{"finalOFX":{"0":"276.67"},"0":null}`, `finalOFX` o objeto que contém: `{"0":"276.67"}` e `0` o objeto que contém `"276.67"`

Você deve fazer algo similar a isso:

```js
var dados = {"finalOFX":{"0":"276.67"},"0":null};

alert(dados.finalOFX["0"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta selecionar qual **key** você quer, neste caso é **0**.

Exemplo:

```
alert(dados.finalOFX[0]);
```